# How would you design database tables to keeps track of a status property?

Tags: database, database-design

I would like to ask for your opinion about a question even though I already got mine so that I can see if my thinking is coherent or not. I won't expose my opinion at first in order not to influence anyone (in a way or another).

Basically I have a table for storing some kind of object data. Those objects have a status that can change and I need to keep track of those status changes. Now I would like to know how you would design the rest of the database to do so.

In addition I can tell you that a status change is made at a certain time that must be remembered as well. And finally you must be able to determine what the current status is at any time. The question is actually more related to how you would store and read the current status.

Please do not hesitate to ask me if you need more info to answer. I just don't want to give too much in order not to influence the answers.

PS: I do not need trigger related answers

Answer (score 4):

Basically you want a status history table separate from the object table.

```
objects [id, name, ...]
status_history [object_id, status, valid_from, valid_to]
```

Optionally you can include current status and timestamps in objects table if you need it - it will certainly speed up queries when you need to know just the current status (which is often most of them) for the cost of maintenance.

If you want to historize more attributes than just status or the entire record you could stay with a single table:

```
objects [id, seq_number, name, ...., status, valid_from, valid_to]
```